# Ruby and pointers

Tags: ruby, pointers

I'm programming a Dungeon Generator for a litte game.

Dungeons are made of rooms. A `room` has `connections` to other rooms.

`room.connections = [room_a, room_b]`
and
`room.number = 1 # unique id`

Now I need to pick a room by it's number.

I did this first with a `recursive_scan` method, which did not work because rooms can lead into circles, which throws a StackOverflowError. So I put an array called `already_scanned` with the room numbers, which were already picked into the args of the method. Then it didn't scan all rooms - btw, I have no idea why, by my logical undstandness it should have worked.

Then I tried to put all rooms also in an array and then iterate the array for the wanted room - but here I get the problem, every room is basically connected to every other room, at least with some other rooms betwenn it; so the array gets as big as `dungeon_size * array_of_rooms.length`.

What I need now is an explicit pointer - I know almost every var in ruby is a pointer, except Fixnums and Float (and maybe some other). Even though, the array gets to big, so I need a real pointer.

(I also tried to setup an array of object_ids and load them via ObectSpace, but sadly - because I often have to load the rooms - the rooms with the wanted object_id are already recycled then, as an error message explains.)

This is my recursive scan method:

```
def room(number)
  recursive_scan(@map, number, []) # @map is the entrance room
end

private

def recursive_scan(room, number, scanned)
  scanned << room.room_number
  if room.room_number == number
    room
  else
    r = nil
    room.connections.each do |next_room|
      if !scanned.include?(next_room.room_number)
        r = recursive_scan(next_room, number, scanned)
      end
    end
    r
  end
end
```

Comment: From what you described `recursive_scan` with `already_scanned` should work, I used exactly the same approach for an edge finding algorithm not too long ago. Maybe post your code and we'll see if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything in Ruby is already a reference.

Why not just maintain a room index?

```
rooms[room.number] = room
```

Then you can get anything with `rooms[i]`.  I would keep the index up to date incrementally by simply modifying the *initialize* method of Room.

```
def initialize
  rooms[self.number] = self
  . . .
end
```

This won't take up much space because the array is just an index, it doesn't actually have copies of the rooms. Each reference obtained from the array is essentially the same thing as a reference obtained via any other mechanism in your program, and the only real difference between the reference and a classic pointer is a bit of overhead for garbage collection.

If rooms are ever deleted (other than just before exit) you will want to set the `rooms[x] = nil` when on deletion.

I don't see why you need to create the data structure first and then index the rooms, but FWIW you should be able to do that recursive enumeration and use the rooms presence in the room index array as the been-here flag. I'm not sure why it didn't work before but it really has to if written carefully.

Comment: I should add that you might want to make the `rooms` index be a *class variable* of `Room`.  So: `@@rooms[self.number] = self`

Comment: I had this solution already done, but because I need to convert the rooms `.to_yaml`, I get an array not with just references, but with a size that is `all_rooms * array.length`.

Answer (score 3):

It is a classical graph problem. Using graph library will handle most of these issues. Try using the `rgl` gem.

Define each room as a vertex in the graph. The connections will be the edges.

```
require "rgl/adjacency"

map = RGL::AdjacencyGraph.new
rooms.each {|room| map.add_vertex room}
rooms.connections.each {|room1, room2| map.add_edge room1, room2}
```

Now you can test whether two rooms are directly connected in O(1):

```
map.has_edge? room1, room2
```

Or get the list of all rooms:

```
map.vertices
```

You can also get the list of all adjacent rooms:

```
map.adjacent_vertices(room)
```

Answer (score 1):

A really [hackish](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/ObjectSpace.html#M001525) way to get all Rooms in memory would be:

```
all_rooms = ObjectSpace.each_object(Room).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [NArray gem](http://narray.rubyforge.org/), which will speed up using arrays of numbers.  You may be trying to force a square peg into a round hole here with this approach.

Comment: If you need to speed up a linear search, just turn it into an O(1) operation instead ;)