# Ruby and pointers compared to other languages?

Tags: c++, arrays, ruby

I am fairly new to ruby but coming from a C/C++ background and I believe I have basic knowledge within how computers and programming work.

In C++ if you would like to create a pointer which will point to a value you will specify it as a pointer: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/.

Example:

```
int x = 3;
int *p = &x;
*p = 4;
std::cout << x;
```

Which makes sense to me because now `p` is pointing to the address of `x` and therefore when we change the value of `p`, `x` will change as well. `x` will in this case output 4.

But when I run:

```
a = []
b = a
a[0] = 3
p b
# => [3]

c = "this is a string"
d = c
c.upcase!
c = "the string has been edited"
p d
# => THIS IS A STRING
```

In ruby, `b` outputs `[3]` where it for me should output nothing. And `d`outputs `"THIS IS A STRING"` and not `"the string has been edited"`. [Ruby and pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116386/ruby-and-pointers) is another question where they go through how you can use pointers in ruby.

**My question is:** Why are arrays seen as pointers in ruby and how does it work? Is `b`pointing to `a`'s address as in C++? What makes a variable change what it is pointing to? For example: if `a = b` when will `a != b`? Why are integers not pointing to the address of another variable?

Comment: `c =` is a reassignment. The variable `c` now has nothing to do with the former `c`. `c.replace("edited")` would modify `c` in place and hence `d` will get the changes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general - ruby variables hold references, not pointers to the values. When you assign:

```
a = [3]
b = a
```

`b` references the same array as `a`. It's the same with strings.

Worth reading:
https://robertheaton.com/2014/07/22/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/

EDIT:

```
a = [1]
b = a
b
# => [1]
a = [2]
a
# => [2]
b
# => [1]
```

Comment: And if you once more assign `a` to an array it will reference to another array? When: `a=[3]; b = a; a=[];` printing b wont print 3 anymore? @mrzasa

Comment: `a` will point to the new array, `b` will point to the old one. See the edit.

Comment: The edit and article was helpful. Although I do not understand why they are by default used as references? Why are arrays and strings seen as references but integers are not?

Comment: @darclander: What makes you think integers are not reference types?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I might have missunderstood the comments in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208768/is-it-possible-to-use-pointers-in-ruby/7210058. So you are saying all types of variables are seen as references?

Comment: @darclander: Since integers are immutable, it is actually impossible to tell whether they are reference types or value types. In many implementations, they are *implemented* as value types for performance reasons, but it is much easier to think about them as reference types. Why learn two concepts when you can learn one?

Comment: The only way to determine the difference between a value type and a reference type is if you have two references and you dereference one of them and mutate the result. For a value type, the two references will actually reference two different values, so you will observe that one value changes and the other doesn't. For a reference type, you will have two references to the *same* value, and mutating that single value through one of the references will also be observed through the other reference. However, if you can't mutate the value *it makes no difference whether there are two values or one*

Answer (score 5):

> Why are arrays seen as pointers in ruby and how does it work?

They aren't. There is no such thing as a "pointer" in Ruby.

> Is `b`pointing to `a`'s address as in C++?

There is no such thing as an "address" in Ruby. The Language Specification says that when you dereference a variable, it evaluates to the last object that was assigned to that variable. *How* the language implementation does this is completely and utterly irrelevant, and you *shouldn't*, and in fact *can't* know about it. It could use a pointer to memory location. It could use a dictionary. It could print the value out on paper and fax it to a sweat shop in East Asia where child slaves interpret it. (That would be highly immoral, unethical, and illegal, but it would be a perfectly valid implementation.)

> What makes a variable change what it is pointing to?

Assignment, and *only* assignment can change the binding of a variable.

> For example: if `a = b` when will `a != b`?

When the `!=` method is overridden to say so. Which would be a terrible idea, but nonetheless:

```
class Foo
  def !=(*)
    false
  end
end

a = Foo.new
b = a

a != b #=> false
```

> Why are integers not pointing to the address of another variable?

Again, there is no such thing as a "pointer" or an "address" in Ruby, therefore, an integer can never "point" to an "address", simply because "pointing" and "address" are not concepts that exist in Ruby.

Let's step through your code line-by-line:

```
a = []
```

You create a new `Array` object and *bind* the local variable `a` to that new array object.

```
b = a
```

Now, you *bind* the local variable `b` to the result of evaluating the expression `a`. What is the result of evaluating an expression that consists solely of the name of a variable? The variable gets *dereferenced*, i.e. it evaluates to the object that was *bound* to the variable earlier.

In this case, that object is the `Array` that you created on line 1.

```
a[0] = 3
```

This line is simply syntactic sugar for the following line:

```
a.[]=(0, 3)
```

Here, you are sending the message `[]=` passing the two arguments `0` and `3` to the result of dereferencing the local variable `a`. Again, dereferencing the local variable `a` evaluates to whatever the variable was bound to last, which is the `Array` from line 1. The method `Array#[]=` is defined as mutating its receiver such that it places its second argument at the index specified by the first argument.

The method doesn't *have to* mutate its receiver. It could also return an updated *copy* of the `Array`. (Although in this particular case that would be useless since the `a[0] = 3` syntax sugar behaves like assignment and thus will always evaluate to the right-hand side. In other words, the return value of `Array#[]=` would be ignored unless you use the explicit method calling syntax `a.[]=(0, 3)`.)

```
p b
```

Here, we again dereference the local variable `b`, which still points to the exact same object (there was never any re-assignment), which is still the `Array` from line 1.

There was only ever one single `Array` in the entire code. You never created a second one, and you never called a method that would return a new `Array`.

One method that *does* return a new `Array` as opposed to mutating the receiver is the method `Array#+`. Here is an alternate example using `Array#+`:

```
a = []
b = a
a += [3]
```

`a += [3]` is equivalent to `a = a + [3]` which is equivalent to `a = a.+([3])`. So, we dereference `a`, which gives the `Array` from line 1, then we send it the message `+` with the single argument `[3]`. `Array#+` is defined to return a new `Array` which is the concatenation of the receiver and the argument. Lastly, we assign this new `Array` to the local variable `a`.

```
p b
```

The local variable `b` is still bound to the same object, since we never re-assigned it. So, it is still bound to the `Array` from line 1. We never changed this `Array`, ergo, this prints `[]`.

On to your second example (I'll go a bit faster this time):

```
c = "this is a string"
```

Create a new `String`, assign to `c`.

```
d = c
```

Bind `d` to whatever `c` is bound to, i.e. the `String` from line 1.

```
c.upcase!
```

Send the message `upcast!` to the `String` obtained by dereferencing `c`. `String#upcase!` is defined as mutating the receiver. So, the `String` that is being referenced by both `c` and `d` has now changed itself.

```
c = "the string has been edited"
```

Create a brand-new `String` that has nothing to do with the other one and assign it to `c`.

```
p d
```

`d` was never re-assigned, ergo, it is still bound to the `String` from line 1.

Comment: Hi Jorg, can you read it - https://medium.com/techtrument/the-basics-of-variable-assignment-in-ruby-ca8daf478e6e

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I've done any ruby programming, but for what I remember:
For short, int are stored by value, complex type are stored by pointer

For exemple:

```
a=3
```

This will create a memory place holder where any id for the type 'int' is stored and the value itself is stored aswell (3).

While:

```
a="Toto"
```

This will initialize the place holder with the id of the type "string" and a pointer to another memory holding "Toto"

This is why:

```
a=3
b=a
a=6
```

a will be 6 and b will be 3 (not changed by the instruction a=6)

While:

```
a="Toto"
b=a
a.upcase!
```

a and b will be the same string